# Quickfixj rejecting incoming message with "Tag appears more than once" where there is no repeated tag

Tags: quickfixj

Quickfixj is rejecting the following logon message:

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=163|35=A|34=77086|1128=9|49=XXxVENUExXX|56=XXxUSxXX|52=20140704-11:24:22.308|108=4|98=0|1137=9|789=78069|58=RFA:f718fdb8-2ed3-4e0b-965f-4305188d06f9|1409=0|1407=100|10=013|
```

The actual log entry for it is:

```
20140704-11:24:22.316 ERROR [QFJ Message Processor] quickfixj.errorEvent - FIXT.1.1:XXxUSxXX->XXxVENUExXX: Rejecting invalid message: quickfix.FieldException: Tag appears more than once, field=1407: 8=FIXT.1.1^A9=184^A35=A^A34=77086^A49=XXxVENUExXX^A52=20140704-11:24:22.308^A56=XXxUSxXX^A1128=9^A58=RFA:f718fdb8-2ed3-4e0b-965f-4305188d06f9^A98=0^A108=4^A553=USRC^A554=test234^A789=7806 9^A1137=9^A1407=100^A1409=0^A10=093^A
```

Tag 1407 doesn't appear more than once though. We're using Quickfixj 1.5.3. With a FIX Version 5.0 SP2 - EP100 data dictionary. I can't see any issues with the data dictionary entries. The Logon message fields are all flat (except for the optional MsgTypeGrp which is not being used). Have tried with ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder as both Y and N. Config entries are:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=4
FileStorePath=/dir/storeLoc
FileLogPath=/dir/logLoc
StartDay=sun
StartTime=09:55:00
EndDay=sun
EndTime=09:45:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
AppDataDictionary=/dir/dicLoc/QuickFIX_EP100.xml
TransportDataDictionary=/dir/dicLoc/QuickFIX_EP100.xml
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
EnableNextExpectedMsgSeqNum=Y
# Only the SP2 version supported
DefaultApplVerID=9
DefaultApplExtID=100
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
TargetCompID=XXxVENUExXX
TargetSubID=XXxSUBxXX
# Endpoint
SocketConnectHost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SocketConnectPort=XXXXX

[SESSION]
SenderCompID=XXxUSxXX
SenderLocationID=XXxLocxXX
```

Anyone have any ideas what could cause this. It couldn't be because there is '1407' in today's date?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide the data dictionary? As it hard to find out the problem everything seems to be fine.